# Is there a TV show/movie with humanoid aliens evolved from elephants?

Tags: story-identification, aliens

Before we get started, be aware that this may just be a figment of my imagination.

I have a memory from some years ago (late 90s/early 2000s) of seeing a picture of humanoid aliens evolved from elephants in a sci-fi magazine (probably [*SFX*](https://www.gamesradar.com/sfx/), from the UK).

From the picture in my head, the aliens still had an elephant-like trunk on their face, but were humanoid. (I don’t recall how large their ears were, or whether said ears were shaped like Africa or India.) I think this alien was wearing some sort of space suit, though not with a helmet.

I thought this was a promo shot from *Stargate-SG1*, but [I can’t find any mention of humanoid/elephant aliens in *Stargate*](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Elephant).

I also can’t find any mention of such a fictional creature via Google. The nearest I get are [the Elcor from *Mass Effect*](https://masseffect.fandom.com/wiki/Elcor) (who don’t look like my memory), and [the Engineers from *Prometheus* when they’ve got their helmets on](https://aliens.fandom.com/wiki/Mala'kak) (also not particularly close to the picture in my head, and not designed at the time I remember seeing this).

Did my brain just make this up?

Comment: The book [Footfall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Footfall) comes to mind, though of course that is not (AFAIK) made into a video production.

Comment: Are you getting this confused with [Ganesha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganesha), the Hindu god?

Comment: @hardmath: hmm, yeah I see the resemblance. (And I’m glad there are at least some intelligent elephants in sci-fi, it seemed like a concept that should have been mined more than my Googling suggested it had.) Mine were definitely bipedal though.

Comment: @Wikis: Ganesha’s definitely pretty close, although I remember the alien wearing some sort of space suit. I’ve now Googled “space ganesha” but [this](http://fc08.deviantart.net/fs70/f/2010/177/5/f/Ganesha_by_leaa7.png) isn’t quite what I had in mind either.

Comment: Howard Tayler's Schlock Mercenary is a web comic that features many species of animals from Earth having gained intelligence due to genetic manipulation; for an example with elephants see http://www.schlockmercenary.com/2002-05-26... No video though.

Comment: [Found one with a helmet](http://imgur.com/r/pics/0hLSh0R)

Comment: @SJuan76: hey cool. Mine was definitely a photo (if indeed it existed at all), but at least someone’s gone down the intelligent elephant road.

Comment: You said the Engineers weren't designed at the time you saw it, but their elephantine helmets were based on the original "Space Jockey" that appeared in *Alien*, closeup [here](http://images2.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20081014170719/aliens/images/archive/2/26/20081014171305!SpaceJockey.jpg)--any chance you saw a photo of that?

Comment: @Hypnosifl: yeah naw the thing I remember was essentially an elephant, as if evolved into a human — definitely alive, rather than bones.

Comment: The recent film Jupiter Rising had a character called Nesh who was a humanoid elephant person.  Here's a link: https://jupiter-ascending.fandom.com/wiki/Nesh

Comment: I was thinking of Babar, until the space suit...

Comment: Any chance its something from The Fifth Element?

Comment: https://images.app.goo.gl/HXEGC5t8PzA2fZ2y5

Comment: @DannyMcG: now that, I like.

Comment: @dominicfonde: I don't think so: I saw The Fifth Element twice around the time of its release, so I suspect I'd remember. I reckon I pretty much just imagined this.

Answer (score 8):

Do you mean Max Rebo from *Star Wars*?

[image: Max Rebo]

> Max Rebo, whose real name was Siiruulian Phantele, was a male Ortolan who was known as a popular musician and head member of the Max Rebo Band. He was a skinny Ortolan, the youngest of five children.
>
> [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Max_Rebo)

Comment: Ah, he’s probably the closest I’ve seen so far. The guy I remember/invented was more obviously based on an earth elephant though — grey skin, wrinkled trunk.

Answer (score 3):

While it's fantasy, not sci-fi, is it possible you're thinking of the [Loxodons](https://gamelore.fandom.com/wiki/Loxodon) from *Magic: the Gathering* or the [Loxo](http://www.spelljammer.org/chars/races/Loxo.html) from *Spelljammer*? The latter are even technically aliens, having come from a different crystal sphere.

Comment: Ooh, the Loxodons are kinda close. Again, I remember it as a photograph (as if from a movie or TV show) rather than an illustration, but as it’s looking like my actual memory never existed, maybe this is what I saw.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - from the fantasy genre, there's also the race of beings from "Tower of the Elephant", which is a Conan story. The creature Conan found is basically a humanoid body with an elephant head, and in the comic version his story is illustrated with images of his race in spacesuit-like armor.

Answer (score 3):

How about the poster for Captain Eo at Disney? Note the little elephant guy in a space suit.

[image: Captain Eo movie poster]

Comment: Is that a musical Star Wars film featuring Michael Jackson? HOW HAVE I NOT HEARD OF THIS?!

Comment: That’s reasonably close — definitely not what I imagined, but it’s a humanoid elephant, which is more than a lot of the other answers. Good shout.

Comment: @PointlessSpike: I suspect you’ve already looked this up, but [Captain EO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_EO) was essentially a short film shown as part of an attraction/ride at Disney theme parks, rather than something that was released in cinemas. Marvellously, it looks like it’s [available in its entirety on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCXgORuMvyw) (although you’ll have to supply your own lasers/smoke/vibrating seats/screaming young children).

Answer (score 2):

I think I saw that movie too. Here's a clip from the film called [Los Nuevos Extraterrestres](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086026/) or the Pod People. Is this the movie you're thinking about?

Comment: Could you explain why this movie match the request by adding details, screenshot,or at least a link ? We like sourced answers :)

Comment: Definitely not, but I see why you thought so.

Answer (score 2):

The recent film [Jupiter Rising](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1617661/) had a character called [Nesh](https://jupiter-ascending.fandom.com/wiki/Nesh) who was a humanoid elephant person.

[image: Nesh]